# how to merge database same row as one with addition of value

Tags: php, yii

This is my database :

```
owner_id    qty    status 
   1         20      in
   1         30      out
   3         10      in
```

This is my php code to get all fields in yii :

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) 
{$sp = Inventory::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"product_id=".$_POST['id']));}
```

It's give me result as database 
in I need to merge owner_id 1 with addition in qty

> need result like if i pass id 1 then result like

```
owner_id  qty  status
 1        50   {'in',out'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use group_concat and group by

```
 select  owner_id, sum(qty), concat('{', group_concat(status), '}')
 from my_table 
 group by onwer_id 
 where  owner_id =1
```